# How to map additional Get()?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes

In this asp.net core 2 web api app, how do I get the 2nd Get() to work with these URLs:

```
api/class2/var1
api/class2/var1/50
```

Right now, only `api/class2/var1` works.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Class2")]
public class Class2Controller : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Get() returned";
    }

    [Route("api/class2/var1/{id?}")]
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "Get(id) returned";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set up your controller like this.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class Class2Controller : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Get() returned";
    }

    [HttpGet("var1/{id?}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return $"Get({id}) returned";
    }
}
```

If you need more information on routing go here:
[Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)